# How to bind model in Kendo UI?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, model-binding

I have problems with binding model after create action using Kendo UI with Angular.

After create request in debug mode I successfully acheved needed action call in PoController, but object which controller must accept is empty.

In Fiddler I can watch request '/PO/Create' with body:

> models=%5B%7B%22id%22%3Anull%2C%22po_number%22%3A%221%22%2C%22note%22%3A%22ojklj%22%2C%22valid_start%22%3A%222016-08-09T10%3A06%3A46.703Z%22%2C%22valid_end%22%3A%222016-08-09T10%3A06%3A46.703Z%22%7D%5D

Can somebody help with model binding? May be Kendo UI datasource is wrong configured?

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives"]);
```

**poDataSource.js**

```
'use strict';

app.factory('poDataSource',
    function () {
        return new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                type: "odata",
                read: {
                    url: '/PO/GetAll',
                    datatype: 'jsonnp',
                    type: 'get',
                },
                create: {
                    url: "/PO/Create",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    type: "post"
                    },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                        }
                    }
                },
                batch: true,
                pageSize: 5,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "id",
                        fields: {
                            id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                            po_number: { type: "string" },
                            note: { type: "string" },
                            valid_start: { type: "date" },
                            valid_end: { type: "date" }
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
    });
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<kendo-grid k-data-source="dataSource"
            k-columns="gridColumns"
            k-editable="'inline'"
            k-toolbar="['create']"
            k-sortable="true"
            k-pageable="true"
            k-resizeable="true">
</kendo-grid>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - SWE Team Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.1.226/kendo.common-material.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.1.226/kendo.mobile.all.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.1.226/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.1.226/kendo.material.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.1.226/kendo.dataviz.material.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2016.1.226/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2016.1.226/angular.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2016.1.226/jszip.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2016.1.226/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/app/services/appService.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/app/services/poDataSource.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/app/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="homeController as app">
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("SWE Team Dashboard", "Index", "Home")</p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("PO", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("TMT Tasks", "Tasks", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Task to PO mapping", "TaskPOReferences", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My Telerik MVC Application</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**POController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Dashy.DB.Model;
using Dashy.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dashy.Controllers
{
    public class POController : Controller
    {
        // GET: PO/GetAll
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            var allItems = new PODAL().GetAll();

            return Json(allItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(PO po)
        {
            try
            {
                new PODAL().AddPo(po);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return View();
            }
        }




        // GET: PO/GetTaskToPoMapping
        public string GetTaskToPoMapping()
        {
            var allItems = new PODAL().GetTaskToPoMapping();
            var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allItems,
                new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                });
            return jsonResult;
        }
    }
}
```

**PO.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using NHibernate;

namespace Dashy.DB.Model
{
    public class PO
    {
        public virtual string note { get; set; }
        public virtual int id { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime valid_start { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime valid_end { get; set; }
        public virtual string po_number { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<POLine> po_lines { get; set; }

        public virtual void AddPOLine(POLine line)
        {
            line.po = this;
            po_lines.Add(line);
        }
        public PO()
        {
            po_lines = new List<POLine>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just had a glance I found one issue, variable id is declare as int, but your are sending NULL value in model make it nullable or change the model data `models=[{"id":null,"po_number":"1","note":"ojklj","valid_start":"2016-08-09T10:06:46.703Z","valid_end":"2016-08-09T10:06:46.703Z"}]`

Comment: @Vijai Isn't it mean that id is nullable: id: { editable: false, nullable: true }? Or you mean something else?

Comment: @StanislavMachel , `"[{"id":null,"po_number":"1","note":"ojklj","valid_start":"2016-08-09T10:06:46.703Z","valid_end":"2016-08-09T10:06:46.703Z"}]"` 

you are sending a list to server , but in POST Create Action I can see thare's PO , so it should be `List<PO>` or your client code needs to be modified.
BTW , you can also set something called `DatasourceRequest` in arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answers helps me get correct desicion of this issue. If `batch` is set as `true` it returns list of items, it means that I need re-implement my controller that it can recive `List<PO>`.

But here is also other big problem. In fact this controller return not http response, but return view and better decision is implement WEB API. Bassicaly I needed to re-implement programm.

Here is some changes

**POController.cs**

```
using Dashy.DB.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Dashy.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Inspections;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Dashy.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        private PODAL _podal = new PODAL();

        public IQueryable<PO> GetPOs()
        {
            return _podal.GetAll().AsQueryable();
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage PostPO([Bind(Exclude="id,po_lines")]PO po)
        {
            po.po_lines = new List<POLine>();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _podal.AddPo(po);
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, po);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = po.id }));
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }
        }
}
```

**poDataSource.js**

```
'use strict';

app.factory('poDataSource',
    function () {
        return new kendo.data.DataSource({

            transport: {
                    type: "odata",
                    read: {
                        url: '/api/po',
                        type: 'get',
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: '/api/po',
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "PUT",
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: "/api/po",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                            if (operation !== "read") {
                                debugger;
                                return JSON.stringify(options);

                        }
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 5,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "id",
                        fields: {
                            id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                            po_number: { type: "string" },
                            note: { type: "string" },
                            valid_start: { type: "date" },
                            valid_end: { type: "date" },
                            po_lines : { editable: false, nullable: true}
                        }
                    }


                },
            });
    });
```

**homeController.js**

```
app.controller('homeController', function ($scope, $http, poDataSource, poLinesDataSource) {

    $scope.onChange = function (e) {

        $scope.showPoLines = true;
        var grid = e.sender;
        var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        var selectedItemId = selectedItem.id;

        $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'api/polines/getlines',
            params: { id: selectedItemId }
        })
            .success(function (data) {
                // new push new data to grid dataSource 
                $('#PoLinesGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(data);
                var grid2 = $('#PoLinesGrid').data('kendoGrid');
                grid2.dataSource.transport.options.create.url = "/api/polines/PostPO?=" + selectedItemId;

            })
            .error(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });

    };
    $scope.dataSource = poDataSource;

    $scope.gridColumns = [
            { field: "id", title: "ID" },
            { field: "po_number", title: "PO nr" },
            { field: "valid_start", title: "Start date" },
            { field: "valid_end", title: "End date" },
            { field: "note", title: "Note" },
            {
                command: [{ template: "<button class='k-button' ng-click=''>PO lines</button>", }],
                title: "PO lines"
            },
            { template: "<input type='text' ng-value='calculateTotal(dataItem)' />", title: "Total" },
            {
                command: [{ template: "<button class='k-button' ng-click='showDetails(dataItem)'>Show details</button>", }],
                title: "Show details"
            },

            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: " " }
    ];


    $scope.dataSourceOfLines = poLinesDataSource;

    $scope.gridColumnsOfLines = [
            { field: "id", title: "ID" },
            { field: "total", title: "Total" },
            { field: "note", title: "Note" },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: " " }
    ];
});
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<kendo-grid id="#PoGrid" k-data-source="dataSource"
            k-columns="gridColumns"
            k-editable="'inline'"
            k-toolbar="['create']"
            k-sortable="true"
            k-pageable="true"
            k-resizeable="true"
            k-on-change="onChange(kendoEvent)"
            k-selectable="true">
</kendo-grid>
<div ng-show="showPoLines">
    <kendo-grid id="PoLinesGrid" k-data-source="dataSourceOfLines"
                k-columns="gridColumnsOfLines"
                k-editable="'inline'"
                k-toolbar="['create']"
                k-sortable="true"
                k-pageable="true"
                k-resizeable="true"
                @*k-on-change="onChange(kendoEvent)"*@
                k-selectable="true">
    </kendo-grid>
</div>
```

I hope that solving of this problem can help also other people. Also I thank people who help me find this answer.

Answer (score 2):

`batch` is set to `true`, which means that the Kendo UI DataSource will send all new items in a single request in the following way:

```
models: [
    { FieldName1: "value 1.1", FieldName2: "value 2.1" },
    { FieldName1: "value 1.2", FieldName2: "value 2.2" }
]
```

It seems that the server-side code currently does not expect this.

Either change the server implementation, or disable batch operations. Also keep an eye on your `parameterMap` function, as it also has direct influence on how items are submitted.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-batch

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap

Answer (score 0):

After decoding your URI It looks like following ,

```
"[{"id":null,"po_number":"1","note":"ojklj",
"valid_start":"2016-08-09T10:06:46.‌​703Z","valid_end":"2016-08-09T10:06:46.703Z"}]"
```

here you are sending a list to server , but in POST Create Action I can see thare's `PO` , so it should be `List<PO>` or your client code needs to be modified in such a way that it should send single object.

what I would advice you is , you can also set something called **`DatasourceRequest`** in arguments so you will be able receive all params kendo supports.

more on DatasourceRequest [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-do-i-use-the-datasourcerequest-object-as-an-asp-net-mvc-action-parameter) and [here](http://blog.falafel.com/server-paging-sorting-filtering-kendo-datasourcerequest/)